# Finding index for new folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am given a name and I am supposed to make a dir with this name. If this dir already exists, name of the folder should have _$number as its suffix.

Number is calculated as highest value + 1. Examples:

> Name:awesome
>   Files: dummy awesome awesome_2 awesome_4 dummy_3
>   New folder: awesome_5
>
> Name:awesome
>   Files: dummy dummy_1
>   New folder: awesome

My solution for finding highest value works only for names without special characters. Should the name be for example: **"$#&*!(@*)*(%+#$ asdasd \ ^  sad"**, it fails.

```
function max_item() { 

    local prefix="$1"
    local max="0"

    shopt -s nullglob

    for in_file in * ; do
        if [[ "$in_file" =~ ^"$prefix"_(-{0,1}[0-9][0-9]*)$ ]]; then 

            num="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; 
            [[ "$max" -lt "$num" ]] && max="$num"; 

        fi
    done

    echo "$max"
    shopt -u nullglob
    return 0
}
```

I guess it has something to do with special characters in regex but I have exhausted all my ideas.

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Performance hint: instead of `for f in *` use `for f in "${prefix}_"*` which saves a lot of useless iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for a number at the end of the name, prefixed by an `_`, you could do this instead:

```
max=0
number='^[[:digit:]]+$'
for in_file in "${prefix}_"* ; do
    num="${in_file##*_}"
    [[ "$num" =~ $number ]] && [[ "$max" -lt "$num" ]] && max="$num" 
done

num=$((max + 1))
```

I have incorporated @Jens' excellent suggestion to loop through the just the matching files.

Comment: 123 was right, I was passing the prefix wrong way, my function basically worked, I just called it incorrectly... Nevertheless, your solution with @Jens performance improvement is much better and I shall use it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**Looping in shell code is notoriously slow.**

For *small* numbers, [codeforester's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43918716/45375) is fine, but **starting at around 30 items** (the exact number depends on many factors), the **external-utility-based solution below will be faster and scale much better.**
(For fewer items, an external-utility solution is slower, but that will rarely matter).

The solution below has the added advantage of being more concise:

```
max_index() {
  printf '%d\n' "$(shopt -s nullglob;
                   printf '%s\n' "$1_"* | 
                     awk -F_ '{print $NF}' | 
                       sort -rn | head -n 1)"
}
```

<sup>Note: The reasonable assumption is made that your filenames have no *embedded* newlines.</sup>

- `shopt -s nullglob` ensures that if a globbing pattern (`"$1_"*` in this case) matches nothing, it expands to the null (empty) string.
- `printf '%s\n' "$1_"*` prints all matching filesystem items line by line.
- `awk -F_ '{print $NF}'` outputs the last `_`-based token on each line, i.e., the trailing number.

  - Note: `cut -d_ -f2` would work too, but makes the assumption that only *one* `_` is present in the filename.
- `sort -rn` sorts the trailing numbers numerically (`-n`), in reverse (`-r`).
- `head -n 1` then extracts only the 1st output line, which is by definition the highest number (if any).

Note that `printf '%d\n' ''` outputs `0`, which is effectively what happens if no existing `_<number>` suffixes are found.